# How to find the cluster point of this sequence?

Tags: real-analysis

$(-2)^n
/ (n^2 + 1)$
is the sequence

I already know that I have to look after n odd or even, but I don't know how to find the value of the cluster points. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Do you have a reason to believe it clusters anywhere?

Comment: The exercise ask me to find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that

$$\frac{(-2)^n}{n^2 + 1} = (-1)^n\cdot \frac{2^n}{n^2 + 1}.$$

Thus we can look at the sequence

$$\frac{2^n}{n^2 + 1}.$$

What do you know about the relationship between $2^n$ and $n^2$? Plug in a few values for $n\ge 5$ and try to get a sense for where this sequence is going.